# localStorage Array resets to empty after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I've been through a bunch of the other questions on here about the same issue, but still can't seem to find my issue. I am setting localStorage in my Homepage Component like so

`localStorage.setItem('my_streamers', JSON.stringify(nonDuplicateStreamers))`

and retrieving them in another Component:

`const nonDuplicatedStreamers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my_streamers'))`

While running the App I see that the proper strings are added to the array in localStorage and I can retrieve them in the getItem Component and I populate a list by mapping over the nonDuplicatedStreamers just fine, until I refresh the page when 'my_streamers' goes back to an empty array. I have tried both the following:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('my_streamers')) {
     localStorage.setItem('my_streamers', JSON.stringify(nonDuplicateStreamers))
}
```

and    `localStorage.setItem('my_streamers', JSON.stringify(nonDuplicateStreamers) || [])` 
both those recommended by other stackoverflow questions, however that made it so my localstorage never got updated at all and stayed an empty array. Any information on this would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Comment: Could you post the code  surrounding your call to `setItem` ?
Is it in a useEffect function?

Comment: if (!localStorage.my_streamers) {
localStorage.setItem('my_streamers', JSON.stringify(nonDuplicateStreamers))
}

try this

Comment: @subparry its not in a UseEffect, its just under a few variable declarations, when I put it in a useEffect I had the same issue, nothing was being set at all in localStorage

Comment: @RobertTerrell Tried that as well, same result, nothing at all being set in storage :(

Comment: And where does nonDuplicateStreamers come from?

Comment: @RobertTerrell so I did 
if (localStorage.my_streamers.length < 3) {
localStorage.setItem('my_streamers', JSON.stringify(nonDuplicateStreamers))
}
and that atleast let me set it the first time, but after I enter another value in the input, it doesn't get pushed to the array, and the array is only ["first value"]

Comment: so you're saying once you initially push into the local storage you are no longer able to add more values into the array?

Comment: @RobertTerrell yes exactly, but the initial one stays now atleast, so its a step in the right direction

Comment: how are you attempting to add values to your local storage after youve initially set it

Comment: @RobertTerrell so... turns out since I was setting state with an empty array that was the issue, every refresh set an empty array, i set the state to the getItem and now were good!

Comment: I was wondering about that, I didn't see all of your code so I was going to suggest making the localStorage item your initial state

Answer (score 0):

try something like this because an empty array is still truthy:

```
if (localStorage.my_streamers.length < 1) {
localStorage.setItem('my_streamers', JSON.stringify(nonDuplicateStreamers))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Basically I had written `setItem` `before` `getItem` code so it was resetting it.
If someone is looking out for solution then simply write `getItem` code first and then `setItem` inside function App(){}